# Maximize $8\cdot 27^{\log_{6}x}+27\cdot 8^{\log_{6}x}-x^3$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization, logarithms

> Find the maximum possible value of
>   $$8 \cdot 27^{\log_{6}x}+27 \cdot 8^{\log_{6}x}-x^3$$ $x>0$

How do I deal with the powers which involve logarithm of $x$?

I'm not being able to simplify.

Any suggestion?

Edit:Solved it.It was simple.Just substitute $x^3=6^t$.That makes the expression very simple.Put derivative to 0.x is $6$ simply by observation!

Comment: have you tried taking the derivative using the chain rule a few times?  Remember,  $(b^{(f(x)})'=ln (b) \cdot b^{f(x)}\cdot f'(x)$

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @FlybyNight Sure.Give me some time.I was too sleepy last night to write anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem being obviously (according to the input to Wolfran Alpha) $$f(x)=8\times 27^{\log_{6}x}+27\times 8^{\log_{6}x}-x^3$$ start changing variable $y=\log_6(x)$ that is to say $x=6 ^y$. Replacing, $$f(y)=8\times 27^y+27 \times 8^y-6^{3y}$$ Computing derivatives $$f'(y)=8\times 27^y \log (27)+27\times 8^y \log (8)-3\times  6^{3 y} \log (6)$$ Now, inspection $$f'(0)=78 \log (2)+21 \log (3)$$ $$f'(1)=0$$ So, $y=1$ corresponds to an extremum. Now, the second derivative $$f''(y)=8\times  27^y \log ^2(27)+27\times  8^y \log ^2(8)-9\times  6^{3 y} \log ^2(6)$$ $$f''(1)=-3888 \log (2) \log (3) <0$$ So $y=1\implies f(1)=216$ is the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If you think the dot is multiplication,  I would also guess they intend the reading to be $(8\cdot 27)^{\log_{6}x}+(27\cdot 8)^{\log_{6}x}-x^3$  Now remember that $6^{\log_6 x}=x$.  What can you do with the $8 \cdot 27$? Unfortunately, in this approach I do not find a maximum.

Another reading would be for the first term to be $8 \cdot 27^{\log_6 x}$.  You can do $27^{\log_6 x}=\left(6^{\log_6 27}\right)^{\log_6 x}=6^{\log_6 27\cdot\log_6 x}=\left(6^{\log_6 x}\right)^{\log_6 27}=x^{\log_6 27}\approx x^{1.83944}$

Comment: I think we need to avoid those ugly decimal exponents.The answer is amazingly neat.See here. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8(27%5E(log+x%2Flog+6))%2B(27)(8%5E(log+x+%2Flog+6))+-x%5E3+maxima There must a better way than the brute force derivative..

Comment: @SanchayanDutta:  first we have to know what the problem means.  I found two readings that appear reasonable to me.  Your Alpha page matches my second reading.  I believe a symbolic derivative calculation will get that answer, but haven't tried it.

Comment: So the problem is $8\times 27^{\log_{6}x}+27\times 8^{\log_{6}x}-x^3$